# SKSprite node button does not react like UIButton while being pressed. Swift

Tags: swift

I created a game in Xcode using Sprite Kit and Swift. When I create buttons however, every time I press them they don't look like they are pressed (Highlighted). How can I make it so the button reacts to the touch like a normal UIButton. Attached is the code of an example in my game.

```
let next = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "next")

next.size = CGSizeMake(50, 25)
    next.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/1.1, y: size.height/7.5)
    next.name = "next"
    next.alpha = 1.0
    addChild(next)


override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let location = touches.anyObject()?.locationInNode(self)
    var node = self.nodeAtPoint(location!)

    if node.name == "next" {


        runAction(SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.waitForDuration(0.0),
            SKAction.runBlock() {
                let reveal = SKTransition.moveInWithDirection(SKTransitionDirection.Right, duration: 0.2)
                let scene = StageSelectTwo(size: self.size)
                self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition:reveal)
            }
            ]))
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you made was not a button, but a SKSpriteNode that does something if you touch it. Since it's not a button, it does not inherit the features associated with buttons, such as the highlighted effect.

I suggest you go to main.storyboard and drag a UIButton in the view that you present SKScene to. That way, it'll act like a button, with the highlighted feature.

You'll be linking that button to an IBAction in your view's controller and you can do whatever you want per normal.

Comment: Alternatively, Miles could implement the desired responses in Sprite Kit - for example, animating `node.size` in `touchesBegan`. The nice thing about Sprite Kit is how much customization you can do. (But with simply darkening/lightening a button, a UIButton would be preferable.)